# Matlab filter electical spikes in accelerometric data

Tags: matlab, filter, noise

I have a dataset of accelerometric data that is affected by electical spikes.

I'm looking for a good method to filter out or reduce these spikes as need to calculate on these data a rolling window of FFT and other statistical indicators such as kurtosis and skewness. I can't simply delete these outliers or replace them with NaN.
Sampling 2000[hz]

Until now I've tried on MATLAB 2012b:

- Wavelet denoising (Haar wavelet)
- Median Filter
- Despike and iterpolate approach

Can you suggest a proper approach to deal with these data?

[Download example dataset](http://cl.ly/462d0T0k2r3U)

Comment: Did you try good old low-pass filtering? Why doesn't it work?

Comment: Tried but it cuts off too much informations and it doesn't eliminates spikes :(

Comment: do you know the value marked in green, or are you looking for an automated algorithm to compute this value?

Comment: @user2469775 I do not know the value marked in green.

Comment: A signal like this needs compression.

Comment: You could use `findpeaks` to get all the regular peaks and avarage that value, to get the height of the green lines/threshold

Comment: @thewaywewalk it's an imported audio signal not calculated / I'll also take a look at you code.

Comment: @RickT If you're not doing this online (i.e. live), then why not just discard all points that deviate by more than some threshold value, say 3 standard deviations from the mean for example?

Comment: @Dan if i start discarding points like that in an audio signal artefacts like clicks and pops will be added more so to the signal

Comment: @RickT Well by discard I mean more like replace with a max, or mean or median value. Not just zero.

Comment: @RickT: you get errors, right? The reason is, that your first and last value of your data is already above the threshold. For this case the code doesn't work. If you delete even the first 3 and last 3 values and you set the threshold to 0.04 it's working properly. If deleting values at the beginning/end is no option you need to modify my code somehow, to handle these exceptions.

Comment: @thewaywewalk I tired your code and suggestion and updated my question but I get an subscript indices must be either positive 
integers or logicals when I change Tl and To vaiables to a low number like -0.2 and 0.2

Comment: I see you already found the solution for your problem but regarding your note about only finding median filter for images, an image is a 2D signal. Anything that works for images will also work for a 1D signal. Simply feed your vector to the function and it will work fine.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest some local smoothing. By defining thresholds and averaging all values below and above.

```
Af = data.example1;
% Thresholds
Tl = -0.6;
To = 0.6;

peaks = find( Af < Tl | Af > To);
Af(peaks) = ( Af(peaks-1) + Af(peaks+1) ) / 2;
```

The problem with this approach is that your outliners sometimes consist of up to 6 samples.
So you need to smooth in multiple steps using a while loop:

```
Af = data.example1;
% Thresholds
Tl = -0.6;
To = 0.6;

% initialisation
peaks = find( Af < Tl | Af > To);
counter = 0;

while ~isempty(peaks)
    peaks = find( Af < Tl | Af > To);
    Af(peaks) = ( Af(peaks-1) + Af(peaks+1) ) / 2;
    counter=counter+1;
end
```

after 6 iterations you get the following result:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

I have used the file [`despiking`](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/15361-despiking) from the matlab central file exchange with very good effect for similar problems, though I see you've tried that as well.

Another approach I've taken is to treat the spikes as statistical outliers and removed them using [this function](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/37344-outlier-removal-v2) which uses [Rosner's many outlier test](http://www.itl.nist.gov/div898/handbook/eda/section3/eda35h3.htm). (NIST site is down for obvious reasons, so here is the [Google cached](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:0qVhMfkdeRQJ%3awww.itl.nist.gov/div898/handbook/eda/section3/eda35h3.htm+&cd=2&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=us) version)

Edited to add: I was mistaken. My despiking algorithm did not come from the file exchange function I linked to above. It was actually pulled out of a journal article (the code is listed in the supplementary information to the paper, but they didn't publish the code to the file exchange). The paper was:

**Practical Methods for Noise Removal: Applications to Spikes, Nonstationary Quasi-Periodic Noise, and Baseline Drift**

Delphine Feuerstein , Kim H. Parker and Martyn G. Boutelle

[Anal. Chem., 2009, 81 (12), pp 4987–4994](http://dx.doi.org/10.1021/ac900161x)

Since the copyright is held by the American Chemical Society and the authors, I can't copy the code here, but if you have access to a university library account, you can download a copy. If you don't, I left the link to the file exchange version, but I haven't used it so I can't vouch for its efficacy.

Answer (score 1):

**A moderator merged this question with [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20636125/bringing-peaks-down-to-be-more-in-line-with-the-overall-average-of-the-audio-sig) - that's why it looks a little messy here. This answer considers additional issues in the second question!**

The following is not an entirely clean solution, the code is adopted from [my previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19154067/matlab-filter-electical-spikes-in-accelerometric-data/19160172#19160172), but I added an exception for your case, so you don't need to delete values at the beginning and/or end of your data manually. It discards only these invalid values, that shouldn't cause problems.

```
Af = csvread(strcat('example_data_with_peak.txt'),5,0); 

% Thresholds
Tl = -0.04;
To = 0.04;

% initialisation
peaks = find( Af < Tl | Af > To);
counter = 0;

while ~isempty(peaks)
    peaks = find( Af < Tl | Af > To);
    try
        Af(peaks) = ( Af(peaks-1) + Af(peaks+1) ) / 2;
    catch
        if peaks(1) == 1
            Af(1) = 0;
        else
            Af(end) = 0;
        end
    end   
    counter=counter+1;
end

figure(2);
plot(Af)
```

[image]

For determining the threshold you could use somethink like this, but it's also quite brute-force:

```
thresh = 15*mean(abs(findpeaks(Af)));
```

Comment: you're welcome, I added a line, how you could determine the threshold. It's hard to find a better solution with no knowledge about your particular problem.

Answer (score 0):

For others that may need this here's what I ended up using. Here's the data file [data file link](http://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/6576402/questions/example_data_with_peak.txt)

Thanks goes to @thewaywewalk

[Matlab filter electical spikes in accelerometric data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19154067/matlab-filter-electical-spikes-in-accelerometric-data)

```
clear all, clc,clf,tic
aa=csvread(strcat('/tmp/example_data_with_peak.txt'),5,0); %will skip the first 5 rows that are text and zeros
figure(1);
plot(aa)
Af=aa;
% Thresholds
Tl = -mean(abs(aa))*10
To =mean(abs(aa))*10

% initialisation
[peaks_r,peaks_c] = find( Af < Tl | Af > To);
peaks = find( Af < Tl | Af > To);

counter = 0;

while ~isempty(peaks)
    peaks = find( Af < Tl | Af > To);
    try
        Af(peaks) = ( Af(peaks-1) + Af(peaks+1) ) / 2;
    catch
        if peaks(1) == 1
            Af(1) = 0;
        else
            Af(end) = 0;
        end
    end   
    counter=counter+1;
end
counter
figure(2);
plot(Af)
```

Here are the images of before and after.

[image: Before and After]

Answer (score 0):

I find that for the specific problem of **one-point spikes** (which arises in CCD detectors when a cosmic ray discharges a single CCD cell during the exposure) the following algorithm works very well:

```
  N=length(y);
  for i=[3:1:N-2]
    # calculate the means of two nearest neighbours, and two next-nearest neighbours
    y1=(y(i-1)+y(i+1))/2;
    y2=(y(i-2)+y(i+2))/2;
    # if those two means are close, but the current point is far off, it's a spike
    if ( abs(y2-y(i)) > cutoff && abs(y1-y2) < cutoff)
       z(i)=y2;
    endif
  endfor
```

Selecting the best strategy for a good cutoff selection is a separate issue; I tend to have it set to a fixed value based on the typical dark counts in the CCD. One can also use separate levels for what is "close" and what is "far off", like this:

```
    if ( abs(y2-y(i)) > cutoff_far && abs(y1-y2) < cutoff_close )
```

One can also select a different criterion, like the difference between two means is X times smaller than the difference with the spike data:

```
    if ( abs(y2-y(i)) > 10*abs(y1-y2) )
```

Peaks that are wider than a single-point spike survive this process unmolested.

[An example of de-spiked Raman spectrum using a CCD detector](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BeODb.png)