# Matlab best technique to remove outliers in data

Tags: matlab, outliers, nonlinear-functions, nonlinear-optimization

I have 2 columns `x`, `y` of 100 points each. I would like to remove the outliers data and refill their gap with the average value of the points near to them. Firstly, can I do that? is any Matlab function? Secondly, if yes, what is the best technique to make that?

E.g:

```
x = 1:1:100
y = rand(1,99)
y(end+1)=2
```

In this case, not so similar to my problem, I would like to remove value 2 at the end and to be replaced with one similar to their neighbor points. In my case the distribution of the `[x,y]` is a non linear function, having few outliers.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Matlab filter electical spikes in accelerometric data](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19154067/matlab-filter-electical-spikes-in-accelerometric-data)

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what you mean by outlier. If you assume that outliers are more than three standard deviations from the median, for example, you could do this

```
all_idx = 1:length(x)
outlier_idx = abs(x - median(x)) > 3*std(x) | abs(y - median(y)) > 3*std(y) % Find outlier idx
x(outlier_idx) = interp1(all_idx(~outlier_idx), x(~outlier_idx), all_idx(outlier_idx)) % Linearly interpolate over outlier idx for x
y(outlier_idx) = interp1(all_idx(~outlier_idx), y(~outlier_idx), all_idx(outlier_idx)) % Do the same thing for y
```

This code will just remove the outliers and linearly interpolate over their positions using the closest values that are not outliers.

Comment: yes my outliers are more than three deviations from the median. thanks!

Comment: I tried that, is kinda messy! I wish to show you the matlab figures to see the results.

Comment: @user1640255, sure, you can post or send your results. You could also use [`interp1`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/interp1.html#inputarg_method) with the 'pchip' or 'spline' interpolation methods, which might give you more aesthetically pleasing (but not necessarily more "correct") results.