# bringing peaks down to be more in line with the overall average of the audio signal

Tags: arrays, matlab, sorting, signal-processing, octave

I have an audio signals In which sharp peaks are produced. Is there a way for me to bring the amplitude of only these specific peaks down to be more in line with the overall average of the audio signal (like in-between the green lines in the image)? [Link to sample data used to create this](http://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/6576402/questions/example_data_with_peak.txt)

[image]

People have mentioned using median filtering but I only see information in regards to images.

PS: I'm using octave 3.6.4

I tried [the code from this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19154067/matlab-filter-electical-spikes-in-accelerometric-data)

```
aa=csvread(strcat('/tmp/example_data_with_peak.txt'),5,0); %will skip the first 5 rows that are text and zeros
figure(1);
plot(aa)

Af=aa;
% Thresholds
Tl = -0.3;
To = 0.3;

% initialisation
peaks = find( Af < Tl | Af > To);
counter = 0;

while ~isempty(peaks)
    peaks = find( Af < Tl | Af > To);
    Af(peaks) = ( Af(peaks-1) + Af(peaks+1) ) / 2;
    counter=counter+1;
end

figure(2);
plot(Af)
```

**But  If I change Tl variable to -0.2 and To variable to 0.2 I get an error subscript indices must be either positive integers or logicals  Any idea what I'm doing wrong?**

Comment: I answered exactly this question: [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19154067/matlab-filter-electical-spikes-in-accelerometric-data/19160172#19160172) - you said you don't know the green lines? but why not? How did you calculate them?

Comment: @Dan: that is what is suggested in the answer linked with the duplicate flag.